# call of overloaded 'swap(char&, char&)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what is ambiguous about `swap(arr[i++],arr[n--]);` below. Please educate me on my wrongful ways.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T> void swap ( T & a, T & b )
{
    T temp = b;
    b = a;
    a = temp;
}

template <typename T> void reverse_array ( T * arr, size_t n )
{
   size_t i = 0;
   while (i < n) swap(arr[i++],arr[n--]); // problem line
}


int main () 
{
   char mystr [] = "Obama smokes";
   reverse_array(mystr, sizeof(mystr)/sizeof(char));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code should compile, and does with Clang 3.5 and GCC 4.9.

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Is your *entire* program?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with either g++ or MSVC. Is this **the real code**?

Comment: Not "compiling" on http://codepad.org/

Comment: Hm, http://codepad.org/mJBWhYNu, the site says it uses  g++ 4.1.2

Comment: Please disregard the comment I just deleted. THank you. Now for coffee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[codepad has an implicit `using namespace std;`](http://codepad.org/qt0AxCO3), which is a really bad idea and makes your `swap` conflict with `std::swap`. You can use `::swap` instead, but not before [fixing your bounds problem](http://codepad.org/6TyP0ykS) by passing `sizeof mystr - 2` instead of `sizeof(mystr)/sizeof(char)`.

Comment: What's with the `- 2`, as opposed to a `- 1` to ignore the terminating nullbyte?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: `n` in `reverse_array` seems to indicate the index of the last element to swap (`n--`) rather than the size of the swapping area.

Answer (score 0):

As @minitech mentions in his answer, the problem is because of the implicit namespace declaration, e.g. `using namespace std;`

With that I get the following error, which shows that the conflict is with `std::swap`:

```
    100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/csi_projects.dir/main.cpp.o
    /home/vsnyc/ClionProjects/main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void reverse_array(T*, size_t) [with T = char; size_t = long unsigned int]’:
    /home/vsnyc/ClionProjects/main.cpp:151:52:   required from here
    /home/vsnyc/ClionProjects/main.cpp:144:43: error: call of overloaded ‘swap(char&, char&)’ is ambiguous
         while (i < n) { swap(arr[i++],arr[n--]); } // problem line
                                               ^
    /home/vsnyc/ClionProjects/main.cpp:144:43: note: candidates are:
    /home/vsnyc/ClionProjects/main.cpp:134:28: note: void swap(T&, T&) [with T = char]
     template <typename T> void swap ( T & a, T & b )
                                ^
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                     from /home/vsnyc/ClionProjects/main.cpp:1:
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:166:5: note: void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = char]
         swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
         ^
```

Comment: Apparently GCC 4.1.2 didn't give very descriptive errors, or Codepad just cut it off.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2 and that does. I am also liking the new [C++ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) from Jetbrains :), now I can set breakpoints in the same way I do in Intellij

Comment: GCC 4.1.2 was released eight years ago. I'm not too surprised by worse error messages.